# I need help using string formatting for two pieces of information a user inputs in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to learn Python and an assignment I am doing has the following prompt. I'm in the third chapter and so far this chapter has gone over strings, lists, tuples, sets, dictionaries, data type and type conversions.

> Write a single statement to print: user_word,user_number. Note that there is no space between the comma and user_number.

The inputs I am supposed to test with are `Amy` and `5`

The code is prewritten and below. I am not allowed to edit the first two lines. The corrections/working code must be added afterwards.

```
    user_word = input()
    user_number = int(input())
    
    ''''Your Solution goes here''''
```

So far I have added to where Your Solution goes here is

```
    print((user_word), (user_number))
```

When I added this and used `Amy` and `5` as inputs my output is almost identical. But It needs to show as `Amy,5` with a comma and no spaces. The problem is `,` is the only way I know to separate the variables, comma also adds a space by default giving me `Amy 5` and this is not the solution I need. `[]` and curly `{}` seem to be used for multiple different operations and the context seems to determine how it works. The comma will not show. even when I add it.

```
   print((user_word), ',', (user_number))
```

This goes and adds a bunch of spaces also. If I use apostrophe `'` it prints the string and not the value of the variables the user typed in. If I remove all the spaces and commas I get errors after the IDLE interpreter runs. Also I can't eve get a `.` to show up right after the last letter there is always a space.

I also tried to use

```
   print('{:s}'.format(user_word), '{:d}'.format(user_number))
```

but again it seems to miss the comma. The "user" the program that my work is ran through is never going to add "Amy,".

Comment: `print(f"{user_word},{user_number}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `fstring`, which is a string that allows you to format it very easily, like this -

```py
print(f"{user_word},{user_number}")
```

or you can use string concatenation, like this -

```py
print(user_word + "," + user_number)
```

another way is to set the print separator string to an empty string

```
print(user_word, ",", user_number, sep='')
```

Anyways, I suggest you read about f-string and string formatting in general.